# Fetching a field from an empty Payload struct

Tags: json, go

I'm new to Golang and using a [Go library](https://github.com/go-playground/webhooks) for processing some webhook events from Github.

I've access to a Deployment's `Payload` struct defined here:

https://github.com/go-playground/webhooks/blob/v3/github/payload.go#L384

The library parses the webhook JSON payload and constructs that. This is a custom field, i.e. it's a hashmap/dictionary whose fields can be custom set by the client.

So I think it's being defined as an empty struct by the library. How do I extract a specific field called "foo" from this struct?

Comment: You cannot, an empty struct has no fields and therefore there is no way for you to access "foo". If it is the case that the github json can return a valid object for the "deployment.payload" key then that means that the package's definition of the type is invalid, maybe it's a mistake, maybe they had a reason. I recommend you create an issue on github. Alternatively you can fork the repo, change that field's type to a `map[string]interface{}` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Now there are certain limitations on what you are able to achieve, but by using the reflect package you can easily check to see if your object is empty or not:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"reflect"
"strconv"
)

type emptiness struct {}

type thing struct {
    stuff string
}

func main() {
    e := emptiness{}

    t := thing{
        stuff: "present",
        }
    fmt.Println(t.stuff)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(t)
    fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(v.NumField()))
    v = reflect.ValueOf(e)
    fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(v.NumField()))

    if v.NumField() == 0 {
        // handle your empty object accordingly
    }
}
```

Edit: Forgot to add the [runnable example's link](https://play.golang.org/p/ukcpYz1mU-p).  you can play with it and get more info using reflect as well but if you just want to check if it's empty, this will work.